# how to blur background for few seconds using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

i was able to find css to blur my content. but when it comes to blur the background and normal the background automatically  after 5 seconds, i was not able to do this. Basically, i just wanted to blur my text when any user clicks on input type button for just only 5 seconds and make the situation normal, through using only pure javascript, html and css.
can anyone please help me in doing this.

```css
.blur   {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<head><title>Calculation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

   PE Ratio
    <input type="number"  id="PE" /><br>
    
  ROCE  
    <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br>
   
  Sales Growth 
     <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br> 
    
   <input type="button" Value="Multiply" style="height: 30px; width: 150px; left: 250; top: 250;"    onsubmit="return false"  onclick="amount.value = (15 -( PE.valueAsNumber/2)) + (40 - (ROCE.valueAsNumber)) + (10-(SG.valueAsNumber))">
  
   <p>Rating: <div id="div1">
   <strong><output name="amount" for="hours rate vat">0</output></strong></div>
   </p>
     </form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Are you using JS to add the `.blur` class? If that's the case, simply use a `window.setTimeout()` to remove the class again after 5 seconds.

Comment: no... i am using div class in html

Comment: I don't understand your question: in your code you are not blurring anything at all, despite your question saying that you've managed to do that.

Comment: i have not added that part of javascript in html code provided above because it was not a solution...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <HTML>
   <head>
      <title>Calculation</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="form">
         PE Ratio
         <input type="number"  id="PE" /><br>
         ROCE
         <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br>
         Sales Growth
         <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br>
         <input type="button" Value="Multiply" style="height: 30px; width: 150px; left: 250; top: 250;"    onsubmit="return false"  onclick="amount.value = (15 -( PE.valueAsNumber/2)) + (40 - (ROCE.valueAsNumber)) + (10-(SG.valueAsNumber))">
         <p>Rating: </p>
         <div id="div1">
            <strong><output name="amount" for="hours rate vat">0</output></strong>
         </div>
      </form>
      <button onclick="blurMe()">Blur!</button>
   </body>
   <script>
      function blurMe() {
        var element = document.getElementById("form");
        element.classList.add("blur");
          setTimeout(function() {
            element.classList.remove("blur");
          }, 5000);
      }
   </script>
   <style>
      .blur {
      filter: blur(5px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
      -moz-filter: blur(5px);
      -o-filter: blur(5px);
      -ms-filter: blur(5px);
      }
   </style>
</HTML>
```

This should be enough to get you started, to make it obvious I'm blurring the whole form.

When you click on the 'Blur!' button, it will call the script 'blurMe()'. This uses the 'setTimeout' function to pause for 5 seconds, with the script that actually performs the blur as a callback. The blur happens by adding the style 'blur' you have created to the form. CSS will then pick this up and style appropriately. If you inspect element on the page, click the button, you will see the class being added.

Hope this helps

Comment: @lewis....instead of removing blur after 5 seconds....when the user clicks the blur button, your code takes a pause and then blur the content.....can you please fix this....I want to remove blur automatically after 5 seconds....

Comment: I've updated my response. This script isn't appropriate for production but should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input").click(function() {
    $("#blurme").toggleClass("blur");
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#blurme").toggleClass("blur"); }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```css
.blur   {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<HTML>
<head><title>Calculation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
   PE Ratio
    <input type="number"  id="PE" /><br>
    
  ROCE  
    <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br>
   
  Sales Growth 
     <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br> 
   <input type="button" Value="Multiply" style="height: 30px; width: 150px; left: 250; top: 250;"    onsubmit="return false"  onclick="amount.value = (15 -( PE.valueAsNumber/2)) + (40 - (ROCE.valueAsNumber)) + (10-(SG.valueAsNumber))" id="input">
   <div id="blurme">
   <p>Rating: <div id="div1">
   <strong><output name="amount" for="hours rate vat">0</output></strong></div>
   </p></div>
     </form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

This snippet uses jQuery, you can rewrite the toggleClass() function like so:

```
function toggleClass(el, cssClass) {
    var elList = document.querySelectorAll(el);
    for (var i = 0; i < elList.length; i ++) { 
        elList[i].classList.toggle(cssClass);
    }
}
```

You can move the `<div id="blurme">` to match what you´d like to blur.

Comment: @seachingsolutions ..... I tried your code but I think it is not working.....can you please provide a working example. I am not so good in coding......thanks....

Comment: @SparshGoyal The solution I provided in the snippet should work.

Comment: I tried it but was not working on my device.....maybe the fault or problem could be from my side.....but anyways, your answer gave me some good idea to solve my problem..and finally found solution....thanks for it.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use event binding in JS,

Here i used two events - focus ( when user selects input ), and blur -  ( when user deselects input )

```
const mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

document.getElementById('myinput').addEventListener('focus',()=>{
  mydiv.style.filter = "blur(15px)";
})

document.getElementById('myinput').addEventListener('blur',()=>{
  mydiv.style.filter = "unset";
})
```

[Link to working code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxvgGg)

Also you can use setTimeout - for setting timer to 5 seconds - and than unset blur for background.